# single signout is not working in keycloak spring security adpter 18.0.2

Tags: keycloak

I have mutliple applications configured under same realm and using keycloak security adapter 18.0.2 library, when I login to one app, it automatically logs me to all other application, that part is good, but when I logout from one app it did not log out from other apps, I see that keycloak sessions were cleared for all the connected clients, all other applications are using old keycloak security context as it did not know about the logout from the opther app where logged out.

I did even try backchannel logout feature, it did not help though, please help with this issue.

Expectation is that It should log all other application sessions when I logout from one app.